# New pads and rotors, left side squeaks when turning right

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, saturn, wheel-bearing

I replaced my front rotors and pads on my 1993 Saturn SL(2?) and made sure I used the supplied silicone grease on the contact points, back of the pads and slider bolts. I made sure the wear indicators were not out too far. I made sure the pads were installed correctly, and I cleaned the hub surface where the rotor seats. I bled the brakes and attained the proper pedal height and feel.

I followed the break-in procedure that the manufacturer posted online. The brakes work well but I had a 'not too loud' squeak or chirp from the left side when turning to the right. I reinspected everything and found nothing obvious.

One thing mentioned when I searched is bearing play. I guess the fresh pads sit closer to the rotor. Any tips on verifying or what constitutes too much play? I have a dial gauge but not sure of the proper procedure. Do I have to simulate the load force when turning?

Comment: Did you checked that the lug nuts are correctly tensioned?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You said "*the fresh pads sit closer to the rotor*". That doesn't make sense in context to what you are asking. Did you mean to say *the fresh pads sit closer to the bearing*? Check out [this video](https://youtu.be/5ybpuQTwoFg) on how to check the wheel bearing / hub.

Comment: Maybe your hub is starting to wear out?

Comment: Also, is the squeak constant or rhythmic? Generally (although not "always") bad bearings cause a rhythmic, pulsing, squeak. If it's more of a constant sound then it may just be something rubbing. Often it's some goofy little oversight that causes things like this.

Comment: I would check the CV boots for integrity.  Brake issues don't vary when turning in my experience.  A bearing makes somewhat more sense, but this is usually a growl or a rumble rather than a squeak.  Brake parts typically do not change their spatial relationship based on turning.

Comment: Maybe a worn wheel bearing?